# Get into the selected text div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one mini question about select text to get in to a selected div.

I have created this demo from [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/PGWKAK) .

In this demo you can see there are one blue button and text in a textarea. I want when i select Select this text. and click the blue button it the selected text should be like this `<div class="selected">Select this text.</div>`  after clicking blue button.

How can I do that. Anyone can help me in this regard ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".Bold", function() {
    // Code goes here...
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.editor {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.editButtons {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.Bold {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="editButtons">
    <div class="Bold">Add in Div</div>
  </div>
  <textarea class="editor" id="editor">Select this text. and click blue button. It should be add the following div tag like this:
    <div class="selected">Select this text.</div>
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: just use the addClass javascript attribute when clicking on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're looking for this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btnSelect").click(function() {
      var $area = $("textarea.editor");
      var area = $area.get()[0];
      var s = area.selectionStart;
      var e = area.selectionEnd;
      if (s == e) return;
      var text = $area.val();
      var before = s > 0 ? text.substr(0, s) : "";
      var selection = text.substr(s, e - s);
      var after = e < text.length - 1 ? text.substr(e) : "";
      
      selection = "<div id=\"selected\">" + selection + "</div>";
      $area.val(before + selection + after);
      return false;
   });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   background-color: #fafafa;
}

.container {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 500px;
   margin: 0px auto;
   margin-top: 30px;
}

.editor {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 30px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.editButtons {
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.editButtons a {
   text-decoration: none
}

#btnSelect {
   padding: 5px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   background-color: blue;
   position: relative;
   max-width: 150px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="editButtons">
      <a href="" id="btnSelect">Select</a>
   </div>
   <textarea class="editor" id="editor">Select this text. and click blue button. It should be add the following div tag like this: <div class="selected">Select this text.</div> </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click",".Bold", function(){
        var textArea = $('#editor');
        var start = textArea[0].selectionStart;
        var finish = textArea[0].selectionEnd;
        var textValue = textArea.val();
        var modifiedText = '<div class="selected">' + textValue.substring(start, finish) + '</div>';
        var finalText = textArea.val().substring(0, start) + modifiedText + textArea.val().substring(finish, textValue.length);
        textArea.val(finalText);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".Bold", function() {
    // Code goes here...
    $('.Bold').html('<div class="selected">Select this text.</div>')
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.editor {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.editButtons {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.Bold {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="editButtons">
    <div class="Bold">Add in Div</div>
  </div>
  <textarea class="editor" id="editor">Select this text. and click blue button. It should be add the following div tag like this:
    <div class="selected">Select this text.</div>
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: If i select another text then what it happen?

Comment: How do you mean? Here in this example you are doing click event on class .Bold and changing html in that class. Can you please specify more detailed about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".Bold", function() {
    // Code goes here...
    $(this).html('<div class="selected">Select this text.</div>')
  });
});
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am confused. Did you want to add a class called selected to the textarea? If so this is how you do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".Bold").on("click", function(){
      $('textarea').addClass('selected');
   });
});

.selected {
   background: black;
   color: white;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. So if user select some text in a textarea and click blue button then js code should do <div class="selected">selected text</div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this - I guess you want to output the selected text?

```js
$("body").on("mousedown", ".Bold", function() {
  $('.container').append('<div class="selected">' + window.getSelection().toString() + '</div>');
  console.log('<div class="selected">' + window.getSelection().toString() + '</div>');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.editor {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.editButtons {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.Bold {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="editButtons">
    <div class="Bold">Add in Div</div>
  </div>
  <textarea class="editor" id="editor">Select this text. and click blue button. It should be add the following div tag like this:
    <div class="selected">Select this text.</div>
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've another solution like this:

```js
function disp() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var t = text.value.substr(text.selectionStart, text.selectionEnd - text.selectionStart);
  alert(t);
}
```

```html
<TEXTAREA id="text">Hello, How are You?</TEXTAREA><BR>
<INPUT type="button" onclick="disp()" value="Select text and click here" />
```

Hope it helps